# Defining multiple global functions in a JavaScript bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

I'm working on a bookmarklet, which needs several functions.  Individually, I can define any function I need by calling something like:

```
javascript:void(window.test1=function(){alert('hi');});
```

But as soon as I try to add a second function, it stops working.

```
javascript:void(window.test1=function(){alert('hi');}window.test2=function(){alert('bye');});
```

Running this generates an error in the console saying "Unexpected identifier".  I have tried separating the two function declarations with a semicolon, a space, and a carriage return (the latter two hex-encoded as %20 and %0A), inserting them between thus:

```
javascript:void(window.test1=function(){alert('hi');};window.test2=function(){alert('bye');});
```

This doesn't work either; it yields the error message "Unexpected token".

How do I define two functions consecutively in the context of a bookmarklet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try wrapping all inner function in 1 function and define all needed function in inner function as properties/methods on `window` object as you are doing here.

Thus:

```
javascript:void(function(){window.test1=function(){alert('hi');};window.test2=function(){alert('bye');}}());
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked nicely. I'm going to edit your answer to put in the working code so future visitors will have a finished example.